# change the value of dropdown using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<select name="vehicle_make" onchange="test1(this.value)" style="width: 130px; float:left;" id="vehicle_make" class="home_input">
    <option value="">Choose Make</option>
    <option value="2063">Acura</option>
    <option value="2064">Honda</option>
</select>
```

i have a dropdown. i have read the href attribute of the link and assigned it as the value to dropdown. but i want to take only the number from the link and assign it as value to dropdown how can i do it.

```
<select name="vehicle_make" onchange="test1(this.value)" style="width: 130px; float:left;" id="vehicle_make" class="home_input">
    <option value="">Choose Make</option>
    <option value="http://store.teknotik.com/category-s/2063.htm">Acura</option>
    <option value="http://store.teknotik.com/category-s/2064.htm">Honda</option>
</select>
```

i have used following jquery to get the link as value

```
$("#data a").each(function(index) {
        if ($(this).attr("class") == "subcategory_link") {


            //document.getElementsById("year").innerHTML="<option value="+$(this).attr("href")+">test</option>";
            lnk[cnt] = $(this).attr("href");
            cnt = cnt + 1;
            //alert($(this).attr("href"));

        }
    });
```

but i want to have the dropdown value as:

```
<select name="vehicle_make" onchange="test1(this.value)" style="width: 130px; float:left;" id="vehicle_make" class="home_input">
    <option value="">Choose Make</option>
    <option value="2063">Acura</option>
    <option value="2064">Honda</option>
</select>
```

i want to have only the number before .htm in above dropdownho send as value. Please advise.

Comment: @gdoron hey he is new to stack please don not under-estimate person to use this.

Answer (score 3):

Easy way:

```
$('#vehicle_make option[value!=""]').each(function() {
    this.value = this.value.replace(/\D/g, "");
});​
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/nSfmK/1)

---

```
\d // Numerical char
\D // Not numerical char <===
g  // Is a flag which means find all the occurrences, and not only the first.
```

[**Excellent** regex cheat sheet.](http://www.addedbytes.com/download/regular-expressions-cheat-sheet-v2/png/)

So I'm  looking for all the non numerical chars (with `\D`)and "replace" them with an empty string.

Comment: good answer sir. mind explaining the regex? i'm still a n00b at it myself. I'm assuming "D" finds the decimals in the string... but that's about what i know..

Comment: @nXqd. look at the cheat sheet I just added., it's a great one!

Answer (score 0):

try the `.replace('', '')` function

```
.replace('http://store.teknotik.com/category-s/','').replace('.htm','')
```

should leave you with just the numerical value

Comment: if you use `replace`, use regex like this: `.replace(/\D/g, "");`

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there are two parts here ... getting just the number you want:

```
lnk[cnt] = $(this).attr('href').substring($(this).attr('href').lastIndexOf('/')+1);
lnk[cnt]=lnk[cnt].replace('.htm','');
```

(not the most elegant solution, but should work)

Then setting the value:

```
$("#vehicle_make").val(lnk[cnt])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find it like below ;

```
var url = $(this).attr("href");
var urlTemp1 = url.split("/");
var urlTemp2 = (urlTemp1[urlTemp1.length -1]).split(".");
var yourNumber = urlTemp2[0];
alert(yourNumber);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("select[name='vehicle_make'] option[value!='']").each(function() {
     this.value = this.value.split("/").pop().split(".")[0];
  });
});
```

Hope it helps